# Jmeter execute Logout Action during ramp down

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing

I'm trying to run a scenario that ramps up each thread by logging them in once, loops through an business action for an hour with pacing, and logouts as it ramps down.

Ideally the threads should not log out all at once, as such it I wanted to find a way to execute a logout action for each thread ramping down.

I have tried using stepping and ultimate thread groups, however for ramp down, the threads are being stopped.

In addition, I have tried the following scenario: 1) login, 2)runtime controller scheduled for one hour with the business action, 3) logout. This however, results in premature aborts for the threads that are still executing the business action once it reaches one hour.

Any help, even implementing this in beanshell, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a [TearDown Threadgroup](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group). That will always be executed once your test is over.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a thread group which sets a jmeter property, let's call the property "isRunning", in a pre or post processor, next that thread has a test action set to pause for the duration of the test.  After the pause set the property "isRunning" to false.

When the user logs on in another thread group (your test case) grab the "isRunning" property and store the value in a jmeter variable for the thread.  Once the user logs in put your business case in a while loop with the jmeter variable created using the "isRunning" property as the condtion.

Get the value of the "isRunning" property somewhere towards the end of your business case and update your jmeter variable.  Put the log out controller outside of the while loop.  When the first thread group sets the "isRunning" to false, the while loop in your other threads will finish executing the use case and log out when it sees that the while condition is no longer met.

If you use any type of random think timers and ramp time, the threads should essentially step down on their own, due to ramp time offsetting the start of the use case and random think times.

Not sure if this is the best way to go about this, but I needed to do the same thing you are looking for and this proved to be a feasible workaround.